# How can I disasseble this kitchen cabinet?

Tags: cabinets

I'm trying to disassemble this cabinet so I can get underneath the  bottom panel and clean it - has a nasty fishy smell underneath and will require a comprehensive clean.

From the pics you can see there are no screw or anything on the outside.  From the inside you only see screw at the top left and right panels.  I want to know since the bottom panel doesnt seem to be screw in or anything, how can I take it off.

Is it the case that the hole bottom assembly is done with adhesive.  Therefore I need to unscrew the top, then pry the bottom panel out from the sides?  Can you explain to me exactly how I should do it.  I was pushing the bottom panel up yesterday but I thought it might snap.

Also the bottom panel had to holes which I thought maybe screw but on closer inspection it doesn't look like anything.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the last picture with the two holes?  Where is this located?

Comment: It's a typical flatpack kitchen unit assembled with cam and dowel fixings. This means that to remove the base you would need to pull it out, turn it over, release the cams from the bottom and pull the sides off so that the base can come out. At that point you've dismantled the whole thing... If you're lucky the kickboard might be removable to gain access underneath, if not just remove the unit as indicated in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As opposed to disassembling the cabinet I would just remove it in one piece. Inside at the top it looks like the wood cross member is screwed to the wall. Remove the screws, slice the caulk on the top and the entire cabinet should pull away from the wall.

Comment: I agreed,  It appears to be a standalone unit, remove the two top screws holding it to the back wall.  break the chalking seal on the back of the top counter.  if it still doesn't move, then remove the two screws at the bottom front edge.

Comment: just to add Carl was right in that simply moving the bottom front panel(kickboard) gave access to the underneath area.

Answer (score 1):

You don't remove it.   That may put the cabinet beyond repair as that looks like laminated MDF.   The holes at the bottom are probably for water spillage - so instead of sitting and ruining the MDF it drains down.

After you take the two screws out the biggest thing is the countertop.   Make sure it is not attached.   It may be glued.  You will have to go in with a thin knife and break up glue.   Pull cabinet out and reset it after you clean up in the same place.   You could add some wood glue on top but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: MDF with a fishy smell is probably beyond repair already, as the fishy smell will be soaked into the material.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - flip tip on MDF.   Hit it with poly and takes away any smell and actually when it soaks in, smells like wood.